# Understanding [foo for bar, foo in arr] in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples, such as `[(4, 'c'), (5, 'o'), (6, 'd')]`. I am trying to get better at extracting only the data I need.  I can do it now with for loops or unpacking with zip but Im looking for other methods to expand my knowledge.

I have seen the code below used in several places which extracts the second index of the tuple

```
letters = [ foo for bar, foo in arr ]
```

How does this work? and if I wanted to extract the first index, is that possible?

Comment: Are you asking about tuple unpacking or list comprehension?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[.. for .. in ..]` syntax denotes a [comprehension expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries), specifically one for creating a list as indicated by to the enclosing `[` `]`. Comprehensions generally work similar to [`for` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) in that they allow to *iterate* over something, *assign* or *unpack* each element, and then operate on each element.

```py
[ foo for bar, foo in arr ] 
#                     ^ iterable providing elements
#         ^ assignment of each element to name(s)
# ^ operation for each element
```

Of note is that the assignment in the middle has the same power as using `=` for assignment:

- a single name target is assigned the entire value
  `a = (1, 2)` or `for a in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]`
- multiple name targets are assigned the *parts* of the value
  `a, b = (1, 2)` or `for a, b in [(1, 2), (3, 4)]`

This makes comprehensions convenient to unpack elements and operate on each part individually – for example to combine them or to discard one.

Using proper names for the parts of each element makes it more obvious what is going on, and how to change the result:

```py
>>> # code of the question, using proper names
>>> pairs = [(4, 'c'), (5, 'o'), (6, 'd')]
>>> [letter for number, letter in pairs]
['c', 'o', 'd']
>>> # desired result of the question
>>> [number for number, letter in pairs]
[4, 5, 6]
```

---

[Comprehensions, especially for lists, are a feature found in many programming languages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) They are derived from mathematical "set builder notation" that some people may be familiar with. For example, the mathematical expression "set of numbers in arr"

> { number | (number, letter) ∈ arr}

directly translates to a set comprehension:

```py
#      { number | (number, letter) ∈ arr}
# 
nums = {number for number, letter in arr}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explination.  I would upvote you but need a few more before it will let me .

Comment: @IAskQuestions No worries. Thanks for asking a good question.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the first index in the same fashion:

```
letters_first = [bar for bar, foo in arr]
```

This shorthand technique is called ["list comprehension"](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in Python. The general syntax is

```
[expression for variable in list]
```

Comment: Heads up that neither is the thing between ``for`` and ``in`` restricted to being *a* variable, nor is the thing after ``in`` restricted to be a list. In fact, the code in the question relies on multiple variables being allowed as targets.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was giving an example for a list, but yeah I'm aware "variable" could also be an expression

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [(4, 'c'), (5, 'o'), (6, 'd')]
letters = [ bar for bar, foo in arr ] #  it will extract the first index
```

Answer (score -2):

This is called list comprehension. It creates a list with foo from bar and foo from arr.

Comment: It's worth taking a look at [@MisterMiyagi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68431278/3025856)—which the OP has now accepted, and which has received three upvotes already—as a good example of the level of explanation and detail that makes for an especially useful answer here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Also, please be sure to answer the second part of the question: “…and if I wanted to extract the first index, is that possible?”